# IPTables - block a port on a specific condition

Tags: unix, iptables

New to using IPTables as I am, I have a question which I am hoping stackoverflow can help with before I take the IPTables man file and doing something I regret...

I have an IPtables rule which blocks incoming requests when a specific connection limit is reached:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 7000 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3500 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT
```

My question is, would it be possible to block a ICMP (PING) responses when connections on port 7000 reach a certain limit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you'll need something like fail2ban for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. If you want to block ICMP, please use **-p icmp** instead of -p tcp.

The is one more thing should clarity: ICMP is layer3 protocol, but port number is defined in layer4. So you never find port number concept with ICMP.

(You can check ICMP packet format here : [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792))

Comment: It's not really impossible, but it's very not recommended (crazy idea). You could LOG with iptables after a limit is reached, then a cron would check every minute for any port 7000 in kernel logs. If any port 7000 is found, an iptables rule is activated to drop all icmp.